# socket() return extreme large integer value

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I'm working on a FTP client. I tried to apply a socket id to connect server. Here is my code. Many variables are declared inside the class.

```
    int Client::connectServer() {

        int ret = 0;
        controlSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
        if(controlSocket < 0 )
        {
            cout<<"Creating Control Socket Failed";
            cout<<"err="<<strerror(errno);
            system("pause");
            return -1;
        }

        serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip_addr.c_str());
        serverAddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);  
        memset(serverAddr.sin_zero,0,sizeof(serverAddr.sin_zero));

        ret=::connect(controlSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr));
        if(ret < 0)
        {
            cout<<"Control Socket Connecting Failed";
            cout<<"err="<<strerror(errno);
            system("pause");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

I called this function twice using almost the same code. But one of those didn't work(failed to connect). Then I used the same IP address to debug. The result shows that every thing is the same but the value of `controlSocket`.

When `controlScoket` doesn't been initalized it valued `3131961357`. Then it values `4294967295` after `controlSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);`.I think it's larger than max file descriptors? However `errno` is `0`. On the other hand the normal one values `1932`.

Comment: What is `controlSocket` declared as? It sounds like you declared it as an `unsigned` type. It should be `SOCKET` on Windows and `int` on other platforms. `4294967295` is `-1` as an unsigned value, and `-1` is what `socket()` returns when it fails.

Comment: Also, 3131961357 seems to be [hex speak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak) meaning "BAADF00D" on Microsoft platforms. That's a start.

Comment: Wait, never mind. It means it's uninitialized, which you already knew.

Comment: yes,controlSocket is declared as unsigned int.I'm in windows10 64bit.but how errno is 0 when 'socket()' return -1?

Comment: `0` is `0` regardless if the number is signed. That is not the case for negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks.I'll change the type.The class was not designed by me so I didn't know it well.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. The test should be explicitly `== -1`, not `< 0`. If you're using Winsock you should be comparing it to `INVALID_SOCKET`, not -1.